# Python function not hitting the entire for loop

Tags: python

my function is supposed to take in a list like [9,9,6,6,2] and the list is always given from greatest to least.
it's supposed to return two pairs, in the list where 9 and 6 are 2 pairs that appear in the list.

so my function seems to be working but it only returns (9,) tuple and it's supposed to also include 6 because 6 is also a pair(appears twice in list)
the correct return is (9,6)

it seems like the for s in ... loop is not touching 6, dont know how to fix it

```
def two_pair(ranks):
    """If there are two pair, return the two ranks as a
    tuple: (highest, lowest); otherwise return None."""
    # Your code here.
    iter1 = 0
    listToTup = []

    list_of_same = set(ranks)
    for s in list_of_same:
        if s == ranks[iter1] and s == ranks[iter1 + 1]:
            listToTup.append(s)
            iter1 = iter1 + 1
        #alist = (listTuple.sort(reverse = True))
        alist = (sorted(listToTup, reverse=True))
        atup = tuple(alist)
    return atup
```

Comment: Presumably you always have 5 cards?

Comment: Do you need the performance? Because if not, a much simpler implementation, in just one line, is `for x in set(ranks): ranks.remove(x)`. However, this isn’t the most efficient solution possible on sorted lists.

Comment: [`tuple(k for k, g in groupby(ranks) if len(list(g)) == 2)`](http://ideone.com/0e2m6X)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: my answer contains a slightly more efficient version that doesn't build `list` objects for each group.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: If the expected `len(list(g))` is `2`; I don't know what version would be more efficient. If the expected `len(ranks)` is `5` then a more efficient version should probably use an explicit `for`-loop instead of `groupby()` (I haven't measured it -- just from my experience that I know often shouldn't be trusted for time performance questions).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: fair enough; worst case there are 5 list objects to be created, vs. 5 frame objects for generator expressions. And 5 global `len` and `list` lookups plus calls, vs. 5 `sum` global lookups plus call. It doesn't really matter most likely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is entirely incorrect and can only ever find the first pair, but *only* if the set of `list_of_same` is the same as the first element of `ranks`. *This is not a given* as sets have no set order.

In your case it so happens that `9` is the first listed, so `rank[0] == 9` is true, and so is `rank[1] == 9`. But you then increment `iter1` by 1 only, so the *next* value you test (either `6` or `2`, is never going to be found at `rank[1]` as that was found to be equal to `9` already.

You can remedy these issues by sorting the set (`list_of_same = sorted(set(ranks), reverse=True)`) and using `iter1 = iter1 + 1` *outside* of the `if` test.

You also never test if only *two* pairs have been found; you should return `None` in that case but your function will always return a tuple, no matter what input was given.

There is a simpler approach to be used here. If your input list always contains just 5 elements (a poker hand), then if there are two pairs your `set` will always be of length 3 (since there *must* be a non-paired card in the hand); if not, simply return `None`.

To find the pairs, look at the *preceding card*; if they are the same, it is a pair; your list is sorted after all:

```
def two_pair(ranks):
    """If there are two pair, return the two ranks as a
    tuple: (highest, lowest); otherwise return None."""

    if len(set(ranks)) != 3:
        return None
    pairs = []
    preceding = None
    for card in ranks:
        if card == preceding:
            pairs.append(card)
        preceding = card
    return tuple(pairs)
```

If you are not averse to using the standard library, then using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) would be another good way to group your cards (already sorted) and simply test their lengths to filter on just pairs. If you didn't find two pairs you return `None`:

```
from itertools import groupby


def two_pair(ranks):
    """If there are two pair, return the two ranks as a
    tuple: (highest, lowest); otherwise return None."""

    pairs = tuple(card for card, group in groupby(ranks)
                  if sum(1 for _ in group) == 2)
    return pairs if len(pairs) == 2 else None
```

The `sum(1 for _ in group)` trick counts the number of elements in an iterable as efficiently possible.

Both approaches make use of the fact that `ranks` is sorted from highest to lowest to return `pairs` in reverse sorted order too.

Comment: "This is not a given as sets have no set order" do you mean the list being passed in? if so the List is always given in descending order

Comment: @purplehaze: no, the `list_of_same` set created from the `ranks` list. `set(ranks)` creates a set, and has no specific order; looping over that set can return the 3 numbers in any order Python may choose.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you increase `iter1` only when the condition evaluates to true.

you should unindent the `iter1 = iter1 + 1` statement so it always happen even if the current iteration is not a pair one.

Comment: That the algorithm manages to find `9` as a pair at all is purely by chance, because the order of `list_of_same` is arbitrary. Only if the *first* element yielded is `9` does the loop work.

Comment: ugh Python why you do this to me. Indent error really... but thank you :D for finding it i couldn't on my own

Comment: BTW - in the last iteration the `rank[iter1 + 1]` will result an overflow. make sure you take care of that too.

Comment: In other words, in spite of all the upvotes, this is *far from the complete story*.

Comment: I acknowledge that @MartijnPieters 's answer is the more thorough one :)

Comment: @GabrielAmram gave me what i asked for, and martijn Pieters went above call of duty. Thanks to both, i will write my own algo though

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you a better answer than the rest of the people but I can shorten your code by quite a bit:

```
    def two_pair(ranks):

        newlist = []

        for i in set(ranks):
            if ranks.count(i) == 2:
                newlist.append(i)
        newlist.sort(reverse = True)
        newlist = tuple(newlist)
        return None if newlist == () else newlist
```

The `count` method counts the number of times a value appears in the list. If it appears twice I append it to a `newlist` and return that list as a tuple.

Comment: thanks this was ultimately what i ended up with and  going with because it seems to be the most generic sol

Comment: @purplehaze: it does but isn't very efficient (it'll loop over your N ranks K times, plus another O(LlogL) for the sort, where K is the number of unique numbers in `ranks` and `L` is the number of pairs. It also doesn't return `None` if there are no two pairs.

Comment: I could edit it to return `None` but I just posted this for the result that purplehaze wanted. BTW epic name @purplehaze

Comment: Incorrect. Your submission did not return the correct result for the input [10, 10, 5, 5, 2],. Your submission passed 2 out of 3 test cases. This was also after putting in none.. thanks @Loupi haha

Comment: I ran it for `[10,10,5,5,2]` and got the output (10,5)? isn't that correct?

Comment: if len(set(ranks)) != 3:
        return None
    is the only addition i made and it seems to fail.

Comment: Edited just now for `None`